# How to check if any app is installed on the device or not?

Tags: php, sharing, whatsapp

I want to check with the help of php If I can  write condition to check if any app exists on the android phone or not

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER You may please check with the example link I have mentioned it even I was surprised to see that it is possible

Comment: I too need similar functionality...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the website is only looking if the devices is mobile. As far as I know, you can't for example make a list of the apps installed on a device. Just look if the visitor visits from a mobile device. You could implement this with the Mobile Detect class for example: http://mobiledetect.net

```
<?php
    // Include and instantiate the class.
    require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;

    // Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
    if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
        // Display WhatsApp share button
    }
?>
```

Comment: This for mobile detection not app detection

Comment: That's what I said. I gave him an example of detecting if the user is a mobile user because he will not be able to detect if WhatsApp is installed.

Comment: yeah..saw that..sorry :P

Comment: Thanks for the answer PUBLISHEDMeteor

Answer (score 0):

You **CANNOT** - in any way can detect if an app is installed on a device or not. Although you can detect by several ways if a device is mobile or not using server-side or javacsript techniques, you cannot detect if a certain application is installed or not. You can only send get or post requests to another website - ATMOST.
 Even if you know that a particular user has installed the application, you cannot send a request directly to the app though the app can send data to a web application.